# Compute coverage_fraction using .sampleRegions in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I need to extract pixel values from various ROIs (polygons). I need to extract the pixel values of each band, some properties contained in the attribute table of the polygon and I also need to calculate the % of the pixel covered by the polygon.

According to the documentation for `ee.Image.sampleRegions` there is no option to calculate `coverage_fraction`.

Can someone explain to me how to do this?

The `exactextractr` R package does allow this (https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr) but I would like to be able to implement it from GEE.

Comment: Hi, what shape of the polygon are you using? Is it something common/east to observe or is it more complicated tailor-made shape?

Comment: @Meki21 The shapes of each polygon are varied since they are agricultural parcels in my case.

Comment: Hmm well I am not exactly familiar with the in-built methods for GEE, but one way of checking whether a point is inside a polygon is to draw a vertical (or horizontal) line and see how many edges of a polygon it intersects. If it is odd, then its in a polygon.
Taking this approach and generalise it, you can take a matrix of points and for each check how many intersections. Then you count the ones that are in and you have your answer:)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a “coverage” image from any geometry by taking a constant image (or any image unmasked in the relevant area) and clipping it to the geometry, then using the clipped mask of that image: `ee.Image(1).clip(region).mask()`. Then, add that as a band to your original image and sampleRegions will include values from it:

```js
var samples = image
  .addBands(ee.Image(1).clip(region).mask().rename('coverage'))
  .sampleRegions({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection([region]),
  });
```

[Runnable example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/565332960ff6b7da762ebafa421fd00c)